# Global data as String in JSON format saved in SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

Is correct in Android to save my global data in a JSON format String and access it through SharedPreferences when I need it?

Comment: Technically it's correct as SharedPreferences is meant to store primitive data , that is a string , int , bool etc. unless storing the parsed values of JSON is not an option. I dont see why you would do that?

Comment: This method would probably work. However once you have gone to the trouble of expressing your data as JSON, you can persist it easily by saving it in a private file. Shared preferences ultimately use the file system for persisting data as well. I don't see any advantage you get by wrapping your json in a preference before saving it.

Answer (score 0):

I would extract it and save it as a string before using it in shared preferences. It is easier for the app to read the string rather than the JSON formatted response.

Therefore do something similar to this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();

editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); // Storing integer
editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value"); // Storing float
editor.putLong("key_name", "long value"); // Storing long

editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

As you can see in the above, there is no predefined sharedpreference for a JSON object or array. Hence it is easier to extract the data from the JSON repsonse to a string and pass on that string in the SharedPreference.

Hope this helps :)